# Creating dataframes for each table in a schema using f-string in dictionary comprehension

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to create a `df` for each table in a schema, I achieved it like so:

```
query = """
        SELECT * FROM information_schema.tables 
        WHERE table_schema = 'my_schema'
        """

def res(table,con):
        query_table = f"""
                SELECT * FROM 
                my_schema.{table}
                limit 5
                """
        return pd.read_sql_query(query_table,con) # I ommited the connection information
        

my_tables = pd.read_sql_query(query,conn)
tables = [x for x in my_tables.table_name]
tables_res = {name: res(name,conn) for name in tables}
```

I previously tried to achieve it like so:

```
query = """
        SELECT * FROM information_schema.tables 
        WHERE table_schema = 'my_schema'
        """

query_table = f"""
                SELECT * FROM 
                my_schema.{table}
                limit 5
               """

        
my_tables = pd.read_sql_query(query,conn)
tables = [x for x in my_tables.table_name]
tables_res = {name:  pd.read_sql_query(query_table,conn) for name in tables}
```

But this fails as I do not change the `table` variable in `pd.read_sql_query(query_table, conn)`, is there a way to pass a variable to `f-string` in such a way that it works in a dictionary comprehension?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To change the table variable and save it in a `dict`, I would rather use `format` like so :

```py
>>> query_table = """
...     SELECT * 
...     FROM my_schema.{name}
...     limit 5
... """
>>> tables = ['table_1', 'table_2', 'table_3']
>>> tables_res = {name : query_table.format(name=name) for name in tables}
>>> tables_res
{'table_1': '\n    SELECT * \n    FROM my_schema.table_1\n    limit 5\n',
 'table_2': '\n    SELECT * \n    FROM my_schema.table_2\n    limit 5\n',
 'table_3': '\n    SELECT * \n    FROM my_schema.table_3\n    limit 5\n'}
```

So your code can look like this :

```py
query = """
    SELECT * 
    FROM information_schema.tables 
    WHERE table_schema = 'my_schema'
"""

query_table = """SELECT *
FROM my_schema.{name}
limit 5
"""
   
my_tables = pd.read_sql_query(query,conn)
tables = [x for x in my_tables.table_name]
tables_res = {name: pd.read_sql_query(query_table.format(name=name), conn) for name in tables}
```

Or like your last version :

```py
query = """
        SELECT * FROM information_schema.tables 
        WHERE table_schema = 'my_schema'
        """

def res(table,con):
        query_table = """
                SELECT * FROM 
                my_schema.{table}
                limit 5
                """
        return pd.read_sql_query(query_table.format(table=table), con)
        

my_tables = pd.read_sql_query(query,conn)
tables = [x for x in my_tables.table_name]
tables_res = {name: res(name, conn) for name in tables}
```